# Spring boot RestAPI nested JSONObject is empty

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-boot

I have a problem with a JSON request to my REST Api.

My request is something like:

```
{"task":"get_objects","data":{"guid":"1234"}}
```

But when I want to read the "data" object in my controller it's empty.
I get an error: `org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["guid"] not found.`

**ApiController.java:**

```
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ApiController {
    @Autowired
    private AssemblyRepository assemblyRepo;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<JSONObject> sendResponse(@RequestBody AppRequest request) {
        String task = request.getTask();
        JSONObject data = request.getData();
        String guid = data.getString("guid");
        String password = data.getString("pwd");

        //Do some stuff with the data
    }
}
```

**AppRequest.java:**

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class AppRequest {

    private String task;
    private JSONObject data;

    public String getTask() {
        return task;
    }

    public void setTask(String task) {
        this.task = task;
    }

    public JSONObject getData() {
        System.out.println("AppRequest getData: " + data);
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(JSONObject data) {
        System.out.println("AppRequest getData: " + data);
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

I also tried to change the "data" from `JSONObject` to `String` but then I get the message `Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token`
I really don't see what I'm doing wrong here ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you are trying to work with `JSONObject` and not a `POJO` class? if not try something like:

```
class Data {
  String guid;

}

public class AppRequest {
   Data data;
}
```

and then

```
request.getData().getGuid();
```

then you don't have to work with `Serializers`

Comment: I think as well, that this is a fix.

Comment: Thanks. That helped.

But now I'm struggeling with a JSONArray within a JSONObject. Something like `{"task":"get_objects","data":{"guid":"1234","sup_objects":[{"obj_type":"NT","obj_key":"MS"}]}}`

How would I solve this?

Comment: Add an arraylist of the type you want

Comment: Arraylist of the pojo type

Comment: That's what I've tried. I added `ArrayList<SupObject> supObjects;` to the `Data` class. And the `SupObject` class contains `private String obj_type;`
and `private String obj_key;` with getters and setters. But it's not working

Comment: Listen I'm not next to computer, in 2-3 hours I'll be back and will be able to help you

Comment: OK. Thanks very much. No hurry... I'll be back on monday ^^

Comment: when you say it's not working - which error are you getting? also please add the full code. it's possible that it's not working because your `FasterXml` is not configured to read underscore names. rename `obj_type` to `objType`, `obj_key` to `objKey`

Comment: It's working now... my `sup_objects` object` in the controller was of type `List<SupObject>` instead of `ArrayList<SupObject>`
Now everything's fine. Thanks